# Show that a process is a local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, local-martingales

We have the following setting

> We have a 2-dimensional Brownian motion $(X,Y)$, and we define the process $M_t$ as $$M_t=e^{X_t}\cos(Y_t)$$

The problem is to show that the process $M_t$ is a local martingale, and that we have that $$\langle M\rangle_t=\int^t_0e^{X_s}ds$$

I know that $M_t$ would be a local martingale if it is a continuous, adapted process and if there exists a sequence of stopping times $(\tau_n)_{n\geq0}$, such that $\tau_n\uparrow\infty$ almost surely, and that $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t}-M_0)_{t\geq0}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale for all $n$.

However, I am not aware of any straight forward way to proving that something is a local martingale, and I do not see an easy approach to proving it directly from the definition. Are there ''standard'' routes to follow when trying to prove that a process is/isn't a local martingale?

Moreover, when trying to show that the quadratic variation of $M$ can be written in such a way, I cannot figure out why the cosine term would drop out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we apply Ito's lemma to the function $f(x,y) = e^x \cos(y)$ you'll find that 
$$dM_t = M_t dX_t - e^{X_t} \sin(Y_t) dY_t$$
since $\langle X \rangle_t = \langle Y \rangle_t = t$ and $\langle X,Y \rangle_t = 0$. Since the stochastic integral against a continuous local martingale is again a local martingale, this shows that $M_t$ is a continuous local martingale. We also deduce from this that
$$d \langle M \rangle_t = M_t^2 d \langle X \rangle_t + e^{2X_t} \sin(Y_t)^2 d\langle X \rangle_t = e^{2X_t} (\cos^2(Y_t) + \sin^2(Y_t))dt = e^{2X_t} dt$$
(where we have again used that $\langle X,Y \rangle_t = 0$) and so
$$\langle M \rangle_t = \int_0^t e^{2X_s} ds$$

Comment: Thanks alot, very clear explanation.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how you obtained $$d \langle M \rangle_t = M_t^2 d \langle X \rangle_t + e^{2X_t} \sin(Y_t)^2 d\langle X \rangle_t$$ From $$dM_t = M_t dX_t - e^{X_t} \sin(Y_t) dY_t$$ I can kinda see what you did by just comparing the equations but I'm not entirely familiar with the rules you used. I know that we have for a constant $c$ that $\langle cX\rangle_t=c^2\langle X\rangle_t$, but we aren't dealing with constants here, right?

Comment: Sure. Written out fully $dM_t = M_t dX_t - e^{X_t} \sin(Y_t) dY_t$ means $M_t - M_0 = \int_0^t M_s dX_s - \int_0^t e^{X_s}\sin(Y_s) dY_s$ and so $\langle M \rangle_t = \bigg \langle \int_0^t M_s dX_s - \int_0^t e^{X_s}\sin(Y_s) dY_s \bigg \rangle_t$. Now use bilinearity and symmetry of the quadratic variation since $\langle \int_0^t F_s dN_s, K_s \rangle_t = \int_0^t F_s d \langle N,K \rangle_s$ for continuous local martingale $N,K$ and an adapted process $F$ such that $\int F dN$ makes sense. Note that we don't get any cross terms between $X$ and $Y$ since $\langle X,Y \rangle =0$

Comment: I've just seen the edit to your comment. It looks like you didn't know about the behaviour of the Ito integral with respect to the quadratic variation. This is an important property to keep in mind. In fact $\int_0^t F_s dN_s$ is the **unique** process such that for all continuous local martingales $K_t$ we have $\langle \int_0^t F_s dN_s, K_s \rangle_t = \int_0^t F_s d \langle N,K \rangle_s$ (and one can even use this observation to give an alternative construction of the Ito integral).

Comment: Alright, thanks alot. Perhaps I am getting confused with the notation, but I learned in my lectures that $$\Big\langle\int^\cdot_0 N_s dK_s\Big\rangle_t=\int^t_0N_s^2d\langle K\rangle_s$$ So I am not sure if I can also apply this is the $\cdot$ is a $t$, like in your solution. I mean, obviously it can be applied, but is the $\cdot$ just a notational thing or have you never seen this before? Because if this can still be applied, I can perfectly follow your solution.

Comment: Oh shoot, the $t$ in my comment should be a $\cdot$, I just copy-pasted that expression and forgot to change it. The thing inside the covariation should always be a process and not a fixed random variable; that $\cdot$ just means you consider the integral as a process and not the integral at any fixed time. You're completely right to point this out. Sorry for the source of confusion.

Comment: Alright, now it all makes sense. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again. Could you explain to me why we have that $\langle e^{X_t},cos(Y_t)\rangle=0$? I recall it had something to do with the fact that the exponential was non-decreasing but I can't seem to find any straightforward reason anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's nothing to do with that. Try applying Ito's lemma to both of them and then use the resulting formula to compute the covariation. Recall that $\langle X,Y \rangle = 0$ and that if $V_t$ is a finite variation process then $\langle M,V \rangle = 0$ for any semimartingale $M$.

Comment: In general, when you see a function of a continuous local martingale (/semimartingale) then you should almost immediately try seeing if applying Ito's lemma can help you.

Comment: Alright, I'll get on that. Thanks alot!

Comment: Since the stochastic integral against a continuous local martingale is again a local martingale, this shows that Mt is a continuous local martingale.
Why?

Comment: Because "this shows that" refers to the fact that I'd just written $M$ as a linear combination of stochastic integrals against local martingales.

Comment: Yes but why is the integral against w local martingale a local martingale!

Comment: by the construction of the stochastic integral against a local martingale (see e.g. Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus by Le Gall). Some texts give very ad hoc constructions that make facts like this more work to get, but it just follows from the fact that the Ito integral against an $L^2$ bounded martingale can be constructed as a map into the space of $L^2$ bounded martingales. Then the Ito integral against a local martingale is defined by localising so that you are in the $L^2$-bounded case. This process gives you a localising sequence for the integral for free.

Comment: I can't really say more than that in comments here sorry because the precise details depend on which construction of the Ito integral you learnt and are far too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check out that book. I have posted a related question to this ( a special case)